# How to get unixtime with typescript

Tags: typescript

I tried below.

`var unixtime = new Date / 1000;`

then, compilation error occured.

`error TS2113: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.`

How to get unixtime with no compilation error ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `+` operator to explicitly convert to a number:

```
var x = +new Date / 1000;
```

Or just use the faster / clearer method `Date#now`:

```
var x = Date.now() / 1000;
```

Comment: Silly question... what is that + operator... just a regular plus?

Comment: Yes, unary plus